# Running a binary as a service in RedHat/CentOS

Tags: bash, service, shell-scripting

I have created a script to execute a binary as a service. But the service does not start the service but when i stop the service it shows multiple pids.

I am using RHEL 7.Here is the complete details

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Usually we run the script as follows `./pipeline --config pipeline.conf`

```
[Unit]
Description=Pipeline service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=cisco
ExecStart=/hfqp/bin/pipeline --config /hfqp/bin/pipeline.conf
```

and the did the following

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start pipeline.service
```

Even this did not work.

here is the error log

```
● pipeline.service - Pipeline service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pipeline.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-04-16 06:29:34 GMT; 19s ago
  Process: 10195 ExecStart=/home/cisco/bigmuddy-network-telemetry-pipeline/bin/executePipeline.sh --daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9962 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 16 06:29:07 matrix-pipeline-b-01 systemd[1]: Starting Pipeline service...
Apr 16 06:29:32 matrix-pipeline-b-01 sudo[10196]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Apr 16 06:29:32 matrix-pipeline-b-01 executePipeline.sh[10195]: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Apr 16 06:29:32 matrix-pipeline-b-01 sudo[10196]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [cisco]
Apr 16 06:29:34 matrix-pipeline-b-01 systemd[1]: pipeline.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 16 06:29:34 matrix-pipeline-b-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Pipeline service.
Apr 16 06:29:34 matrix-pipeline-b-01 systemd[1]: Unit pipeline.service entered failed state.
Apr 16 06:29:34 matrix-pipeline-b-01 systemd[1]: pipeline.service failed.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please complete with your distribution name and version. If you are running a systemd based system, you would save time using a systemd unit.

Comment: The typical approach is to record the PID when you start the process in for instance `/var/run/pipeline.pid`  and check for the existence of that PID  rather than using `ps | grep processname`  - when you still want to grep running processes ; use `pgrep` to prevent grep from matching the `grep` command itself and use the associated `pkill` - but the better answer this day and age is to write a systemd service unit file as @ChaoxiangN already mentioned.

Comment: @HBruijn I tried both creating the Unit service as well as the script. Either ways it is not working

Comment: You can see from the last log snippet that the script you're trying to run as a service is itself trying to sudo to the `cisco` user and failing, because it can't do it without prompting for a password, and that there's no way to interactively ask for the password anyway.

Comment: Don't attempt to make an old-style init script. These are deprecated, difficult to manage and will not work in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked into the below error message?

```
Apr 16 06:29:32 matrix-pipeline-b-01 executePipeline.sh[10195]: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Apr 16 06:29:32 matrix-pipeline-b-01 sudo[10196]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [cisco]
```

It seems cisco user is failing to run a command with sudo privileges as this is most likely an non-interactive script. You could grant passwordless sudo by editing the `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
$ sudo visudo
# Add a line like this to /etc/sudoers
# username ALL = NOPASSWD: /fullpath/to/command, /fullpath/to/othercommand
cisco ALL = NOPASSWD: /hfqp/bin/pipeline --config /hfqp/bin/pipeline.conf
```